# cmake: specifying the install relative path to imported shared library

Tags: cmake, linker, setuptools, pybind11

I would like to link against an imported shared library:

```
add_library(drivers SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
  drivers
  PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libdrivers.so
  )
```

The library I would like to link against is a pybind11 binding library. I try to setup `rpath` so that libdrivers.so will be found in the same directory as the bindings library.

```
pybind11_add_module(pybind11_bindings MODULE srcpy/bindings.cpp)
set_target_properties(pybind11_bindings PROPERTIES
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myproject
    OUTPUT_NAME "bindings"
    SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE
     BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE
  )
target_link_libraries(pybind11_bindings
  PRIVATE drivers
  )
set_target_properties(pybind11_bindings PROPERTIES 
INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN")
set_target_properties(pybind11_bindings PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

Things are installed:

```
install(IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS drivers
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${PMYROJECT_INSTALL_PREFIX}
  COMPONENT bindings
  )

install(
    TARGETS pybind11_bindings
    COMPONENT bindings
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${MYPROJECT_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${MYPROJECT_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${MYPROJECT_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    )
```

To complicate things a bit, this is part of a setuptools project installed with pip and using cmake-build-extension: https://github.com/diegoferigo/cmake-build-extension

After `pip install .` is called, the `site-packages` folder has the expected content, i.e. `site-packages/myproject` contains `bindings.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and `libdrivers.so`.

but:

```
ldd bindings.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

> ../../lib/libdrivers.so => not found

Also:

```
objdump -x bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep RPATH
```

does not provide any output !

Instead, `objdump -x bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` output:

```
Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               ../../lib/libdrivers.so
```

does not show anything,so it does not seem the rpath has been set as desired. Anything I may be doing wrong ?

Comment: If the drivers lib is placed in the same dir as the bindings target (which seems to be the case according to the `install` commands), you should be able to use the rpath to tell the linker where to find the dependencies: `set_target_properties(pybind11_bindings PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN")`

Comment: @fabian : I did some reading about rpath, and indeed your suggestion seems correct to me. But it did not change anything. I digged a bit and found https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/issues/11. I updated my question accordingly. Yet, it looks like I fail to update the rpath for the binding library.